# Did Time Lords grant The Doctor enough regeneration energy to have more than one regeneration?

Tags: doctor-who

In *Time of The Doctor*, Time Lords gave The Doctor regeneration energy using which The Doctor regenerated. Does the 14th Doctor (commonly known as 12th) have any regeneration energy left? Can he regenerate again (using the same regeneration energy)?

Answer (score 3):

The Eleventh Doctor seemed to think so.  When discussing it with Clara just before he took Twelve's face, he referred to this as the start of a whole new cycle.  This implies, but does not confirm, that he has another 12 lives to burn through again, or is "topped up" so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Regeneration energy doesn't give you regenerations. It's what you produce when you regenerate. Where it comes from has never been addressed.

The Time Lords didn't give the Doctor regeneration energy, they gave him a new "cycle" of regenerations. Again, exactly how many was not specified, but we can assume it'll be as many as the producers require.

Comment: Then, what was that golden-colored thing which flown from the crack to The Doctor's mouth?

Comment: Also, your theory isn't compatible with the canon.. From [Regeneration article](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Regeneration) on TARDIS Data Core: `Time Lords were also said to have "packets" of regeneration energy in their bodies, one for each life. These packets could be physically removed from a Time Lord's body, essentially robbing them of their regenerations.`

Comment: @Sachin Shekhar: Based on your comments and Radhil's answer below, my guess would be that the "golden-colored thing" would be another 12 "packets of regeneration energy" (possibly taken from or willingly given up by other Time Lords) in order to restart the Doctor's cycle.

Answer (score 0):

He has at least 12 or 13 regenerations left at this point

Comment: Can you cite any references for this?

Comment: @NiallC.: Yep, at the end of Time of the Doctor, he says it's "A whole new regeneration cycle"